# Is it safe to create an AWS EC2 snapshot of a volume that is attached to a running instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm actually upgrading an instance volumes storage capacity, so I have to create a snapshot of the volume first. It's an 80 gig volume, and I started the snapshot process, but later I noticed that the docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-expand-volume.html) say the instance should be stopped first.

I was actually logged into the instance at the time, and I was booted off because the instance was forcibly *rebooted*. It's now running while the snapshot process is pending.

Is the integrity of the snapshot data at risk because I didn't stop the instance first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A snapshot will first reboot the instance (optional, but default) to prevent issues with data corruption. You should be fine - they recommend a manual shutdown so you can determine when it's OK to do so rather than it happening without warning.

Once the snapshot is initiated you can start the instance back up at will.

Comment: Grand, so there's no need for me to cancel the process, stop the instance manually and start all over again then. By the way, I accidentally chose the option to create an image (AMI) based on the instance that is using the volume. I realize my mistake now, but I just let it continue because that process creates a snapshot anyway. Is that OK?

Comment: @RTF Correct. The only problems you'd encounter with what you did are the same sorts of ones you'd have if someone kicked the power cord out of the server causing an unexpected reboot.

Comment: Incidentally, I think I'll have to cancel the image/snapshot creation process now anyway. The snapshot creation has been pending at 52% for about 30 mins now. I think there's something wrong - EDIT: nope, just forgot to refresh the console ;)